# Post new question cooldown timer is showing wrong warning

Tags: support, bug

I tried to ask a question in this site. While doing so, I get this warning message that says "You can only post once every 40 minutes.". However I have not asked any questions in the past five months. I asked a question on another network and that too was 2 days ago.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most likely someone on your network asked a question somewhere on the network and doesn't have a lot of reputation so far. See for example [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/297570/352819) to [Potential privacy breach due to question rate limit from IP addresses](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297568/352819):

> You can post only in 40 minutes in the network sites in which you have a low rep.
>
> If from anyone in your office with low rep, asked a question in any network site, that should be the reason.
>
> It is a network wide limit for low rep users.